# Is left-aligning the button of a Twitter Bootstrap navbar possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like for the button to appear on the left-hand side of the menu on mobile devices. Is this possible with Twitter Bootstrap?

Here is my markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

**[Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/J0kF9qj7yQ#)**

To quote the official documentation:

> Align nav links, forms, buttons, or text, using the .navbar-left or
>   .navbar-right utility classes. Both classes will add a CSS float in
>   the specified direction. For example, to align nav links, put them in
>   a separate  with the respective utility class applied.
>
> These classes are mixin-ed versions of .pull-left and .pull-right, but
>   they're scoped to media queries for **easier handling of navbar
>   components across device sizes**.

I did try the `pull-left` but I am worried as the official documentation mentions that `navbar-left` is more appropriate - see above.

By the way `navbar-left` does not work for me. Should I go ahead and use `pull-left` despite what the documentation says?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle ...
```

Regarding your question edit, I'm not convinced that `navbar-left` was intended to be used for the toggle button. It has explicit style statements that override what `navbar-left` does.

If you do want to use it, however, it could be done by adding this to your custom stylesheet:

```
.navbar-toggle.navbar-left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/render/dzV8Y8Ttbu)**

Answer (score 7):

You can use "pull-left" but you might have to add some left side padding to the icon bar using "padding-left" to the "navbar-header" div. Please see example below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                      <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header" style="padding-left: 10px">
                          <button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>          
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">            
                                <li><asp:Literal ID="litMenuBar" runat="server"></asp:Literal></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>            
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, my icon used to be at the very left and doesn't look right without using padding-left:10px like you mentioned.