# Bootstrap NavBar to the left side of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the navbar bootstrap example from the website examples

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

It's possible to align to the left the button that show the menu when the page is shrunk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is left-aligning the button of a Twitter Bootstrap navbar possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732159/is-left-aligning-the-button-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-possible)

Answer (score 1):

You could override the navbar-toggle class like this:

```
.navbar-toggle {
      position: relative;
      **float: left;**
      padding: 9px 10px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      **margin-left: 15px;**
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

The starred attributes have been changed.